# Create screen and run command without attaching

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am working on automating a maintenance routine that involves starting and stopping a script that is running in a screen session.  My approach is to kill the screen session, and then restart it and run the command from within a script using the abilities to both create a screen and pass a command without needing to attach to the screen.

However, I am having difficulties with this.  I can create the screen correctly without it attaching using `screen -d -m -S screen_name`.  However, if I run a command based on:

`screen -S screen_name-X stuff "command 1"'echo -ne '\015''"command 2"'echo -ne '\015''`

with the echo -ne '\015' being wrapped with backticks rather than single quotes.  It is to simulate the user pressing the enter key as the commands I use are moving to a directory and executing a script located there.  This command works, but only if the screen has been attached to once it has been created.  As I am trying to automate the process of creating the screen and running the commands within it I would like to avoid having to attach and detach within a script.  I will be trying the suggestion of creating a shell script containing the commands I need to execute within the screen and edit according to my results.

Is there a way to create a screen and run a command within the screen either in one command, or without having to attach to the screen after creating but before execution of the command?

Thanks in advance.

**Update - having tried the suggestion to place the commands I need to execute within a shell script I have been able to successfully create a screen and execute the commands from within the screen, but I am getting the behaviour that when the script stops running the screen closes as well.  This shouldnt be a problem as the script is a logging script that should only stop with the knowledge of the sys admin or through the script I am trying to develop, however it would be preferable to have the screen setup in such a way that the screen does not disappear if the script is stopped.  Is it possible to achieve this behaviour? **

Comment: I ran into this same problem and found a solution on superuser.com for anyone else who stumbles upon this problem http://superuser.com/questions/342463/gnu-screen-cant-stuff-commands-unless-the-screen-is-attached

Comment: To keep the screen open you could use something like: screen bash -c 'echo "test"; /bin/bash'

Comment: For your auto-closing issue, you could use a special `.screenrc` that contains the line `zombie kr`, which will keep a finished window open, and you can press `k` to close the winodw, or `r` to run the command in the window again. I have this for my default .screenrc.

Answer (score 24):

I think you may be running into several issues.

If the command finishes before you re-attach, the screen will go away.  You can demo this by using:

```
screen -d -m ls -l
```

It will run the `ls -l` command, but `screen -list` won't show it as the screen process has ended.

I also have no idea what you are trying to do with this \015 stuff.  Perhaps updating your question would help, as what I think you're trying to do is run multiple commands in a screen session.  This should be as simple as:

```
screen -d -m bash -c "command1 ; command2 ; command3"
```

If these are used a lot, perhaps you should make a shell script that runs just these commands, then use a more simple:

```
screen -d -m /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: is there a way to get similar behavior without the screen detaching immediately? Say I want to start an ssh session and then detach right after; `screen -d -m ssh` will detach at the password prompt before the session is made.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Replacing hte "commandN" with several long-running programs results in nothing showing up in `screen -list`. Also, this doesn't name the screen as the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I was looking to run a python program using this method. I tried to create a sh script to run it, but did not see the screen in the list. Instead I used  `screen -d -m python EventGenerator.py`, which worked great

Comment: That should probably be `bash -c "commands"` instead of `bash "commands"`

Comment: You're right, there has to be -c .

Comment: Would be nice to hear the flags mean?

Comment: but how to leave the screen open after the command has finished?

Answer (score 23):

Start a detached screen

```
screen -dmS <screen name>
```

Execute command in previously created detached screen

```
screen -S <screen name> -X stuff '<CMD>\n'
```

Yes you need to type the enter symbol to submit the command or else it will just add the string to the screen.

http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.screen/2003-09/msg00029.html

Comment: what is 'stuff' ?

Comment: `stuff` is actually a command that copy-pastes another command into a screen session: stuff [string]

Stuff  the string string in the input buffer of the current window.  This is like the "paste" command but with much less overhead.  Without a parameter, screen will prompt for a string to stuff.  You cannot paste large buffers with the "stuff" command. It is most useful for key bindings. See also "bindkey". [cited from https://theterminallife.com/sending-commands-into-a-screen-session/]

Comment: This works really grat, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This did the job for me, without `-c` wasn't working

`screen -d -m bash -c "command1; command2; command3"`

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem before, it was a bug with the cygwin implementation.

What I did was create a ".screenrc_detaching" having only the following command

```
#detach
detach
```

and then start screen with

```
screen -c ~/loginScripts/tempScreenrc/.screenrc_detaching
```

Then you have your screen session and its already been attached and detached and you're good to pump commands to it.

Answer (score 1):

A copy'n'paste way to test previous answers is:

```
 # No sessions:
screen -ls

 # Returns immediately:
time screen -dmS screen_descritive_session_name  bash -c 'sleep 20; hostname >> /tmp/h'

 # New session present:
screen -ls

 # File with return of command was created :)
sleep 20; cat /tmp/h
```

The expect result should be similar to:

```
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-yourusernamehere.
```

(That means no screen-session was previously created)

```
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

(It's the time spent to create screen and detach from it. Almost instantaneous.)

```
There is a screen on:
    20318.screen_descritive_session_name    (20/08/2018 16:29:35)   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-yourusernamehere.
```

(This output show screen sessions available. Created on last command.)

```
sleep 20; cat /tmp/h
```

(This `cat` shows the hostname executed inside gnu-screen)

Comment: and what is the result of such tests?

Comment: You are right, there was no example. I will add.

Comment: much better! merci! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
screen -S test -d -m -- sh -c 'ls; exec $SHELL'
```